# JMeter - Where is the error coming from and why?

Tags: java, jmeter

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:    Received    fatal    alert:    handshake_failure
                    at    sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown    Source)
                    at    sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown    Source)
                    at    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown    Source)
                    at    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown    Source)
                    at    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown    Source)
                    at    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown    Source)
                    at    sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown    Source)
                    at    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown    Source)
                    at    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown    Source)
                    at    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown    Source)
                    at    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:487)
                    at    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
                    at    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
                    at    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
                    at    org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
                    at    org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
                    at    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown    Source)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some kind of context about your error? Improving descriptions will help others the answer your questions (and make the whole SO site much nicer for whoever will take a look at older questions in future).

Answer (score 0):

Please use jdk1.7 . The same problem is resolved just changing the jdk to 1.7. Please try.

1. Install jdk 1.7
2. Change the environment variables
3. Rebooted

Now the https should work.

Comment: same problem, switched to 1.7, but it didn't help